# Am I correctly implementing copy_from_user?

Tags: c, module, kernel, device-driver

I am implementing the write file operation for my module, and I want to know if I'm correctly implementing the copy_from_user function. The module is a tictactoe game, so I take an input from the user. Inputs will be strings in the forms, "01 X" or "21 O" where the numbers represent columns and rows and the letters are their pieces. My write function is as follows:

```
ssize_t tictactoe_write(struct file *pfile, char __user *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *offset){

   char* data = kmalloc(sizeof(buffer), GFP_KERNEL);
   size_t unread = copy_from_user(data, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

   printk(KERN_NOTICE "Written");

   //Return number of bytes not read
   return unread;
}
```

With this implementation would the data pointer be initialized with the user input? Which I can then manipulate through the rest of the module? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *sizeof(buffer)* is not what you expect, it values the size of a pointer while you wanted the size of the pointed value. But your question is too vague to say more, the other parameters are not used, and we do not know if you want to write one input of the form "01 X" and with or without  final 0 or all these input but how much are they etc

Answer (score 0):

To elucidate what @Tarracon meant:

```
ssize_t tictactoe_write(struct file *pfile, char __user *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *offset){

   char* data = kmalloc(length, GFP_KERNEL);
   size_t unread = copy_from_user(data, buffer, length);

   printk(KERN_NOTICE "Written");

   //Return number of bytes not read
   return unread;
}
```

Also, you aren't *implementing* copy_from_user, you are *invoking* it.  Big difference.